# Serialize and add to XDocument

Tags: c#, serialization

```
I have Class Calendar

        public class Calendar
        {
        public static List<ServiceCalendar> DaysOfWeek
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return new List<Calendar>
                        {
                            new Calendar { Id = 1, Code = "Mo", Name = "Mo" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 2, Code = "Tu", Name = "Tu" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 3, Code = "We", Name = "We" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 4, Code = "Th", Name = "Th" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 5, Code = "Fr", Name = "Fr" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 6, Code = "Sa", Name = "Sa" },
                            new Calendar { Id = 7, Code = "Su", Name = "Su" }
                        };
                    }
                }
        public static List<Calendar> MonthsOfYear
            {
                get
                {
                    return new List<Calendar>
                    {
                        new Calendar { Id = 1, Code = "Jan", Name = "Jan" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 2, Code = "Feb", Name = "Feb" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 3, Code = "Mar", Name = "Mar" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 4, Code = "Apr", Name = "Apr" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 5, Code = "May", Name = "May" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 6, Code = "Jun", Name = "Jun" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 7, Code = "Jul", Name = "Jul" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 8, Code = "Aug", Name = "Aug" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 9, Code = "Sep", Name = "Sep" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 10, Code = "Oct", Name = "Oct" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 11, Code = "Nov", Name = "Nov" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 12, Code = "Dec", Name = "Dec" },
                    };
                }
            }


        }

My Serizlization Class 

public static class SerializationUtil
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        public static XDocument Serialize(this object obj)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }

            return doc;
        }
```

I need Serialize two objects MonthsOfYear and DaysOfWeek and add their to XDocument

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();

doc = SerializationUtil.Serialize(trigger.MonthsOfYear);
var daysOfWeek = SerializationUtil.Serialize(trigger.DaysOfWeek)
```

How can I add DaysOfWeek serialization to doc and after deserizlize

Comment: To start with the Calendar class does not have the Id, Code and Name properties, secondly I don't get why you can an extention method for the object type and then do: doc = SerializationUtil.Serialize(trigger.MonthsOfYear);

Answer (score 3):

You can use the WriteTo method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.writeto.aspx

Would something like this fit your needs?

```
    public static XDocument Serialize(this Calendar obj)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();

        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Calendar");

            foreach (var dayOfWeek in obj.DaysOfWeek)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("DayOfWeek");

                writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", dayOfWeek.Id.ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Code", dayOfWeek.Code);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", dayOfWeek.Name);

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            foreach (var monthOfYear in obj.MonthsOfYear)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("MonthOfYear");

                writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", monthOfYear.Id.ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Code", monthOfYear.Code);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", monthOfYear.Name);

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Or improve your code to something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var document = CalendarService.DaysOfWeek.Serialize();
    }
}

public static class CalendarService
{
    public static List<Calendar> DaysOfWeek
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Calendar>
                    {
                        new Calendar { Id = 1, Code = "Mo", Name = "Mo" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 2, Code = "Tu", Name = "Tu" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 3, Code = "We", Name = "We" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 4, Code = "Th", Name = "Th" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 5, Code = "Fr", Name = "Fr" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 6, Code = "Sa", Name = "Sa" },
                        new Calendar { Id = 7, Code = "Su", Name = "Su" }
                    };
        }
    }
    public static List<Calendar> MonthsOfYear
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Calendar>
                {
                    new Calendar { Id = 1, Code = "Jan", Name = "Jan" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 2, Code = "Feb", Name = "Feb" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 3, Code = "Mar", Name = "Mar" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 4, Code = "Apr", Name = "Apr" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 5, Code = "May", Name = "May" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 6, Code = "Jun", Name = "Jun" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 7, Code = "Jul", Name = "Jul" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 8, Code = "Aug", Name = "Aug" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 9, Code = "Sep", Name = "Sep" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 10, Code = "Oct", Name = "Oct" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 11, Code = "Nov", Name = "Nov" },
                    new Calendar { Id = 12, Code = "Dec", Name = "Dec" },
                };
        }
    }
}

public static class SerializationUtil
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XDocument Serialize(this object obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }

        return doc;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Calendar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}